# How to use a config file to connect to database set by user

Tags: vb.net, app-config, configuration-files

I have a program that will run a query, and return results in report viewer.  The issue is we have 10 locations, all with their own local database.  What I'd like to do is have each location use the program and utilize the App.config file to specify which database to connect to depending on which location you are.  This will prevent me from having to create 10 individual programs with separate database connections.  I was thinking I could have 3 values in the app.config file "Database" "login" "password"  Generally speaking the databases are on the .30 address... so it would be nice to be able to have them set the config file to the database server IP...

For example:

Location: 1
DatabaseIP: 10.0.1.30
Login: sa
Password: databasepassword

Is it possible to set something like this up using the app.config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a simple XML File to do this.  I used this [site](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/69450-writing-and-reading-xml-files-vbnet-part-ii/) to accomplish it.  I first wrote the XML using the form load, then switched it to the read.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on the resource files.
Originally, they are intended for localization, but they should work for you also.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project Properties, and set up an Application Setting --> Type (Connection String) from the drop down. This will result in a xlm config file in your output directory in which you can modify the connection string post-compile.

Comment: I did a build with this and it didn't show anything in the xml config file... I assume I go to the program properties, then the "settings" tab, and in there is where you are saying I should put the connection string... When I build the program, the xml config file in there, does not show anything about the database connection string.

Comment: Did you use the (Connection String) Setting type? Which should be an "application" setting and not a user setting?